# Create a function that changes the date format from DD/MM/YYYY to Month DD, YYYY. Use arrays to change numerical month to string month name

Tags: javascript

Create a function that changes the date format from DD/MM/YYYY to Month DD, YYYY. Use arrays to change numerical month to string month name.
Example: Input: 31/03/2022
Output: March 31, 2022

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Take a look at the Intl API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: Where are you struggling this this?

Answer (score 1):

```
moment('31/03/2022','DD/MM/YYYY').format('LL');
```

You can use moment.js to format date into your target format, below is the working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/jwbcrn2o/1/